# Is it possible to generate two different IPAs on Xcode 4 using the same project? One for iPhone and one for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, xcode4.3, ipa

I currently have an Universal iOS app, but with the new iPad3 device we needed to add resources/sprites for that specific device, the problem is that the size of the IPA has become incredible larger thanks to the huge new screen. I was wondering if its possible to have only one Xcode 4 Project that could generate two different IPAs, one with target:iphone and other with target:ipad, that could also include or exclude files depending on the file extension, for example blah-ipad.png wont be on the iphone version.
Thanks!

Comment: That would commonly done using separate Xcode `TARGET`s. For the automated separation of your assets, you would have to build a custom built script. So technically speaking, all of this is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Conrad Shultz is correct about why you shouldn't split an existing paid app into two.

For people who haven't released their app, or whose app is free, it's worth knowing that you can duplicate a Target by right-clicking (or control-clicking) on it and selecting Duplicate.  I'm pretty sure Duplication is only offered through this context menu.  The more obvious 'Add Target' options involve creating a whole new Target and manually duplicating the contents and settings of your existing Target.

[image: XCode UI showing Target context menu and Duplicate option]

Once you have multiple targets, you can specify which resources are distributed with each.

**Edit**: you will also need to change the 'Devices' setting if you have an iPhone Target and an iPad Target.

[image: XCode UI showing Target Membership selection for an image resource]

If you have a lot of resources, consider including them in folders with Folder References.  Then you can specify target membership for the entire folder, without having to change individual files.  This will change the path to those resources within your bundle, so plan accordingly.

Comment: Excellent post for those who haven't released an app yet.  Note also that you will need to change your actual build settings, particularly the device family, to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Great post men! It really helps! Just have a question i have a group with multiples images which i converted it to a folder, but i am still unable to change the target for the group?

Comment: Groups are not the same as Folder References.  Groups are for convenience in organising your project in XCode, and have no effect on the compiled app.  They have no Target membership - only the files within do.  To change Target membership of files within a group, you have to select the individual files and change them.  (You can do this by shift-selecting a list of files and checking the boxes to change them all.)

Comment: Folder References, on the other hand _do_ have Target membership - but the files within do not.  You can have the entire folder, or none of it.  Groups are colored yellow, Folder References are blue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

You can certainly set up different build targets (and schemes) for different products, targeting different device families, different architectures, even entirely different platforms (OS X vs. iOS).  You can of course include different assets in each.  I personally do this all the time, so if that's what you're looking to do, let me know and I'll try to provide further details.

But what you *can't* do is submit multiple IPAs for a single product to the App Store.  If you are already distributing a Universal app through the App Store, your only recourse would be to pull it and create two new apps with new bundle identifiers, product names, etc.  (I don't *think*, but I could be wrong on this point, that you can even downgrade a Universal app to a single-family app, but that's something you'd have to check in the developer/App Store documentation and agreements.)

If you went this route, you would force existing users to purchase the new app again at full price.  This would likely be poorly received by customers.  If I were you, I'd look at whether the size difference is really large enough to worry about and, if so, look at strategies for reusing assets across devices (for example, downscaling higher resolution images on @1x devices), though this introduces possible performance penalties.

Comment: Yeah i know i can't submit multiple IPAs for a single App, my question is about two splitting assets, maybe you can provide further details on that point.

Comment: Reading this, it seems obvious that, if `[UIImage imageNamed:]` _only_ finds `@2x` images while running on `@1x` devices, it should scale them down and cache copies in your app's temp folder for later reuse.  Sure, you could implement it yourself, but countless apps would benefit if `UIImage` did it automatically.